# declaring variables as locally as possible and switch statement

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

Some famous code style books recommend declaring vars as local as possible( 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10205934/700825)
My question is : Is switch statement exempt from this rule? For example if all(or most) cases have similar structure and they all use string for similar things should that string be declared in each case or just before switch?

Comment: Code styles are suggestions, not hard and fast rules. They are often good suggestions in order to promote code reuse and readability, but they are still only suggestions. Like all suggestions, the user (you in this case) needs to consider when they should be followed and when they aren't so important... and usually if it's unclear to the point of needing to post about it, it's not so important.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it?

```
switch(cond)
{
    case 1:
    {
      // An inner scope...
      int x;
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to keep them as local as possibile

Pay attention to:

```
switch(1) {
    case 1: int x = 0; // initialization
            std::cout << x << '\n';
            break;
    default: // compilation error: jump to default: would enter the scope of 'x'
             // without initializing it
             std::cout << "default\n";
             break;
}
```

Remember to protect each case block:

```
switch(1) {
    case 1: {  int x = 0;
               std::cout << x << '\n';
               break;
            } // scope of 'x' ends here
    default: {
               std::cout << "default\n"; // no error
               break;
             }
}
```

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Comment: The `default` block should also be protected just the same, if only for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Check if it's feasible to encapsulate the code, you intend to use in case-break block, in a function. I'd suggest only calling functions/methods in case-statements but not having large code-blocks.

Another possibility would be using {} within switch-break. e.g.:

```
case 1:
{
   int i=0;
}
break;
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no noticable difference in terms of performance. In fact, it is probably marginally better to declare variables inside cases, rather than in advance. In terms of readability, it is better to form natural groups of variables, i.e. declare the variables inside each case.

Comment: -1 for "no difference in terms of performance." That's a premature conclusion, even if it's fairly reasonable.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Everything needs to be initialized at some point. I cannot imagine anything changes whether it happens inside the cases or before the switch. Any half decent compiler can move the common elements, anyway.

Comment: Any object that acquires resources will have an impact when case blocks that don't use it are executed. Even if that impact is small.

Comment: Optimizations often consist of combining related operations to skip unnecessary steps. If the compiler can tell that in one case the string is initialized with some characters, then it doesn't need to initialize it as empty beforehand, but declaring it before the `switch` may force it to do so. Whether this makes a measurable difference depends on the application.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious so in terms of performance it would even be better to place stuff inside cases. I guess my answer was too conservative in favor of the inside-cases approach. Edited my answer slightly to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

The rule states `declare vars as local as possible`.
First of all remember that this is just a really good suggestion, not an actual rule.

But beside that, if all the cases have a similar structure, and you decide to declare a single variable just before the case, that is still as local as possible in that case.